# Youtube or Flash File audio extraction?

Tags: php, flash, perl, audio, youtube

Hey Everyone,
I was wondering if there is a current class or library in a web language (php, perl, etc.) that is able to extract audio from flash files or youtube links directly.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to extract audio from a video is to use [FFMPEG](http://www.ffmpeg.org/).  There is a PHP extension available, but I have found it easier (due to installation woes) to just call the binary directly with `exec()`.

Here is a great tutorial for stripping the audio from a video file:  http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#strip

From that tutorial:

`ffmpeg -i mandelbrot.flv -vn -acodec pcm_s16le -ar 44100 -ac 2 mandelbrot.wav`

Now if by "flash files" you mean SWF, that is another matter entirely.

Comment: a few useful ffmpeg commands http://www.catswhocode.com/blog/19-ffmpeg-commands-for-all-needs

Answer (score 1):

Youtube videos use .flv files to contain the video.  These are essentially movie files, so any library that handles them should be able to extract the audio.  On the desktop, I use ffmpeg under linux, which is simple to use at the commandline.  You could probably call it directly from your webpage, if the language supports that, but you could only do that if it's installed, which means it would have to be your server and not a hosted account...

Comment: Add some concrete code/command example to your abstract advice.

Comment: @Brad took care of that; not to long after I answered. I'm not sure why I'd bother to go home and find some examples when I can just upvote a better answer...